# Bash IF logic error

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm just starting to learn bash scripting and to do a sort of hello world program I came up with this:

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
echo "This is a test script"
echo
echo
f="foo"
b="bar"
COUNTER=10
until [ $COUNTER -lt 0 ]; do
    if [ $f="foo" ]; then
        echo first
        echo $f $b
        f="bar"
        b="food"
    else if [ $f="bar" ]; then
        echo second
        echo $f $b
        f="foo"
        b="bar"
    else
        echo neither
    fi
    fi
    let COUNTER-=1
done
```

Now the expected outcome is to clear the screen and say:

```
This is a test script
<space>
<space>
first
foo bar
second
bar food
first
foo bar
second
bar food
...
```

But instead the outcome is

```
This is a test script
<space>
<space>
first
foo bar
first
bar food
first
bar food
...
```

How is is getting passed the first if every time, when the value is "bar". I've tried with quotes, without quotes, double equals...I'm at a loss. can anyone shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

You should add space between after and before brackets on your condition statements:

```
if [ "$f" = "foo" ]; then
else if [ "$f" = "bar" ]; then
```

It's also a good idea to place variables around double quotes to prevent word expansion.

In bash as well, it's recommended to use `[[ ]]` over `[ ]`:

```
if [[ "$f" = "foo" ]; then
else if [[ "$f" = "bar" ]]; then
```

Your loop can also be simplified with for loop:

```
for ((i = 10; i; --i)); do
    ...
done
```

Your extra `fi` is also probably not needed:

```
fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if [ $f="bar" ]; then
```

`]` is actually a (built-in) command, not just part of the shell syntax. It takes one or more arguments, the last of which must be a `]`. In order for the arguments to be recognized, they have to be separated by whitespace.

With a single argument (plus the closing `]`), the `[` command returns false if that argument is an empty string, true if it's non-empty. The argument is sees is `$f="bar"`, which expands to `foo=bar`, which is non-empty and therefore true.

Adding spaces around the `=` should fix this:

```
else if [ $f = "bar" ]; then
```

You also need spaces after the `[` command and before the closing `]`; fortunately, you already do.